# como evitar el error 403 en una llamada AJAX, causado por "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"

Tags: ajax, cors

Tengo un codigo JS que carga una imagen en un canvas para aplicar escala y posteriormente adjunta la imagen resultante a un objeto formData y lo sube al servidor por medio de AJAX, pero me devuelve un error 403 (Acceso Prohibido).
En la consola JS, puedo ver que es algo relativo a las llamadas de distinto origen aunque sea desde el mismo dominio.
Esta es la respuesta:

```
Estado 
403 Forbidden 
Versión HTTP/1.1 
Transferido 434 Bytes 
Política de referencia **strict-origin-when-cross-origin**
```

Exactamente el mismo código lo he usado muchas veces en otras aplicaciones web similares y nunca me ha dado este error.

Esto sucedió desde que migré la aplicación de un servidor compartido con cPanel a un VPS con CWP.

Así creo el formData:

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("imagen", origen);

formData.append("a", destino);

formData.append("urlSave", url);

formData.append("nombre", nombre);
```

Este es el código que tengo para hacer la llamada:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: E_URL + E_VIEW,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"
            },
            success: function(result){...}
         });
```

Comment: Esto vendria siendo mas problema del servidor que del cliente

Comment: Pues si, exactamente eso es lo que pienso, porque ese mismo script JS lo he usado en muchos lugares activos en la actualidad y en todos lados funciona perfectamente. Pero considerando que sea del lado del servidor .. la verdad no tengo idea de por donde debo empezar a revisar para hacer que esto funcione

Answer (score 1):

Bien el asunto consistía en que en el servidor Apache que sirve la aplicación estaba activado el módulo "Mod_Security", y sin ninguna regla, esté módulo se convierte en un policía del que pocas cosas escapan. así que tuve que desabilitarlo y ya todo funcionó, luego me documenté sobre su configuración y las reglas que se pueden usar para dejar pasar sólo las conexiones que me convienen y listo, lo volví a activar y todo OK.